# How to create dynamic table in mySql

Tags: mysql, dynamic-tables

I want to know how to create dynamic table in mySql . I have used dynamic table in Sqlserver 2008 but i am new to mySql . Is it possible ?

Eg: In Sql server i have created Dynamic Customer Table.

```
DECLARE @tblCustomer as table(
            [ ] bit
            ,Sl#        int
            ,custID     int
            ,CustCode   varchar(max)
            ,Customer   nvarchar(max)
            ,Authorized bit
            ,RCount     int)

  SELECT * FROM @tblCustomer
```

Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@sqlstmt = 'whatever sql';
Prepare st from @sqlstmt;
Execute @st;
Deallocate prepare @st;
```

Place the CREATE TABLE statement in @sqlstmt and you are good to go !

The table is a real one. You would have to drop the table afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to do:

```
 CREATE TABLE AS
 SELECT * FROM tblCustomer
```

It will take the existing field types from the schema where possible..

Comment: how can we create a new table with diffrent name from the tblCustomer?

Comment: Just give it the name, like this: `CREATE TABLE companies_test AS SELECT * FROM companies` @BijuKalanjoor